# Не создается страница во ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Есть главное активити, в нем вместо фрагментов хочу использовать View. Табы в заголовками создаются, а сами страници во ViewPager - нет.

**MainViewActivity.java**

```
public class MainViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainViewActivity";

    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    private MyViewPager viewPager;

    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        context = MainViewActivity.this;

        actionbar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_action_bar);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager = (MyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    /**
     * View adapter
     */

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        ArrayList<View> viewList;

        public ViewPagerAdapter() {
            viewList = new ArrayList<>();
            viewList.add(0,new LinearLayout(context));
            viewList.add(1,new LinearLayout(context));
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem add");
            LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) viewList.get(position);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            rootView.setLayoutParams(params);
            container.addView(rootView);
            return container;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return viewList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return "Test title";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В адаптере для ViewPager нужно использовать фрагменты. По-другому никак. Во всяком случае я не знаю способов. А внутри фрагмента может быть любая View в качестве макета. Не очень понятно зачем вам именно View вместо фрагмента. Вкладки создались потому что вы в адаптере указали их кол-во и заголовок.

Comment: просто нашел https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/viewpager-without-fragments/  и http://stackoverflow.com/q/18710561/5634351  и решил протестировать, мне кажется я просто где то какую то деталь упустил

Comment: и почему если tcnm ViewPager -   есть еще FragmentViewPager / FragmentStateViewPager

Comment: Возможно в этом деталь @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

Comment: Вообще странная идея, ИМХО.

Comment: нет, не помогло!

Comment: в примере из статьи в instantiateItem возвращается View который инфлейтится, а у вас который в него же и передается

Comment: похоже это тот момент который я упускал, возвращать нужно было rootView, а не container, спасибо)